# Git - accidentally committed and pushed thousands of images - how to I push without that commit?

Tags: git, rebase, git-commit

I accidentally committed **and pushed** several thousand images and didn't notice until about ten minutes later, when I saw it was till pushing. I canceled it mid-push.

I deleted the offending images, added and committed, and want to push again without the bloated commit.

## gitk screenshot

[image]

Comment: You mean completely remove bad commit from git history?

Comment: Do the good commits contains any files that are built off of those in the "move members..." commit. I would think a simple rebase with delete should work if that is a clean commit.

Comment: Yeah, I also think that squashing 2 commits into one using rebase can work if he can push force to this branch

Comment: Not an issue with `--force` since it's still local. Don't think squash is the way to go. Squash will merge two commits into one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [astrochun suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66271373/1256452), I also believe that an interactive rebase is the way to go here.  However, to make it easy to correct *just* the mistakenly added files, I would use a slightly different route.

Your image—which can't be cut-and-pasted properly, so I haven't even attempted that—shows that you have four commits, with unknown hash IDs (`gitk` puts them elsewhere), that come after the commit identified by `origin/master`:

- The first one of these is the "bad" commit, that includes wanted changes, but also adds all those image files.  Let's assume for now that its hash ID starts with `1111111`.  Its commit message begins with "moved members, tour and vod folders inside a new ...".
- The second through fourth commits are all good ones.  Let's assume for now that their hash IDs are `2222222`, `3333333`, and `4444444`.

If you run:

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

your Git will list out these four commit's hash IDs into a temporary file somewhere.  It will then prepare an instruction sheet that will—outside of its comments that describe how to use it—read:

```
pick 1111111 moved members, tour and vod folders inside a new ...
pick 2222222 deleted tour content
pick 3333333 adds tour/content to gitignore
pick 4444444 deletes unused asset images
```

The way rebase works—interactive or not—is to *copy* the original commits to new-and-improved commits.  At least, we hope the new copies are improved.  The exact mechanism for the copying depends on your Git version, but an *interactive* rebase mostly uses `git cherry-pick` for this, which is usually the best way to do this.  That's why the commands you see are `pick` commands: they mean *do a cherry-pick now*.  Git does a reset to rewind back to the commit you name, in this case the one pointed to by `origin/master`, and then uses repeated cherry-picking to regain the wanted commits.

All you need for Git to do is to *combine* commit `4444444` with commit `1111111`.  To do this, you need to:

1. move the order of the four commands around; then
2. *change* the one for the commit whose hash ID obviously isn't actually `4444444`, but we've been calling that, so that the *command* here is `squash`.

The resulting instruction sheet contains:

```
pick 1111111 moved members, tour and vod folders inside a new ...
squash 4444444 deletes unused asset images
pick 2222222 deleted tour content
pick 3333333 adds tour/content to gitignore
```

This tells `git rebase -i` that instead of *just* cherry-picking commit `1111111`, it should *combine* commit `1111111` with commit `4444444`.  After combining the two—which in this case will result in keeping the changes you want, but dropping the accidentally-added files—Git will bring up your editor on a propose commit message that consists of both commit messages from commits `1111111` and `4444444`.  Your job will be to edit this into a new and improved commit message for this new and improved commit.

We don't know what hash ID this new and improved commit will have, but let's say it's `5555555`, just for concreteness.  Once that commit is made, your Git will go on to cherry-pick commit `2222222` to a new-and-improved commit.  In this case the improvement will be that it comes after `5555555`: otherwise, everything it does is the same as `2222222`.  Then Git will go on to copy commit `3333333` to a new-and-improved commit.  As before, the actual improvement will merely be that it comes in the right place.

Once all commits are copied, your Git takes the branch name `master` and makes it identify the last-made commit.  We don't know what the number will be, but for concreteness, let's call the three new-and-improved commits `5555555`, `6666666`, and `7777777` respectively.  So you'll now have *three* commits, instead of four commits, that go after the *last* commit on `origin/master`.  Those three commits will be the three commits produced by the rebase.

The original four-commit sequence will remain in *your* repository, and be recoverable for at least a month or so.  You can use this if for some reason the three-commit sequence is flawed (perhaps you deleted one too many files in `4444444`, or one too few, for instance).  But if all is right with the new three-commit sequence, you can just keep using that, now.

Comment: Ah, I missed that the latest commit had the fix, so yes, re-organizing and a squash is the way to go. Thanks for the write-up.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure this will work but this is what I would do if I caught it quickly enough. When it gets to be too old you get into issues of removing files where newer commits are dependent on it.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

This will pull up the last 5 commits. Leave the good ones as "pick" and use 'd' or drop for the bad one. Just edit the "pick" text for the bad commit. The options are all available here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History. There's a section called "Deleting commits" that I recommend that you review.

After you "!wq" in vim, follow any remaining instructions.  Note that the first three will be later because it will need to be rebuild, the one that follow was based on the bad commits, etc.

When you're done do a `git log --oneline` to check that everything is what it should be.

Comment: Thanks. There are a lot of other changes in the BAD commit that I need. So I can't just erase the whole BAD commit and all its changes. I think commits only represent changes made since last commit, vs. the entire state of codebase at that point, right? I could delete the bad commit if those changes exist in the later "fixed" commits.

Comment: I see, then maybe `git reset --soft` is the way to go. You can undo commit but still keep changes, then add what you need. But you would have to undo all the good commits, I believe.

Comment: See my other answer on how to reset. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Type `git revert (unwanted commit hash)`
You can get the unwanted commit hash by using `git log —oneline` ,  to get the commit hash e.g cdb76bf

Comment: The issue though is that the original commit will still be there so it's possible to access it from the history as `git revert` only introduce a new commit to revert the bad commit.

Comment: @astrochun yeah, that's the problem. I can revert, but I need all the other changes in that commit, minus the images. Those changes are in the later commits too, but if I push the latest, the bloated commit is still there. I wish you could edit a commit and change .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `git rebase -i HEAD~2`
It will open your default text editor so that you can select the commit you want to.
You can use `git log —oneline` to check, you will not see the commit there

Comment: HEAD~2 won't cover the bad commit. See below. I recommend going back 5 to include the good commit that `origin` has.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said, then I think `git reset --soft` is the way to go.

Not sure what the hash for this commit but you would want to do:
`git reset --soft abcdefg`

where `abcdefg` is the hash of the bad commit.

This will undo all your recent changes up to and including the bad commit.

You might find this page useful: https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/undo-last-commit/